# Problem with API request which returns tab delimited table

Tags: python, csv

When I'm sending request to this API using Python

```
CSVContent = requests.get(f'https://api-audience.gemius.com/v1/available-periods?output=csv&session={token}').text
```

I get tab delimited table

[image]

How can I convert this to csv file?
When I read line by line there is extra row added 
after each line in csv file :-/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYdRG.png)

Comment: ask your question clear

Comment: send some code, show us what you do

Answer (score 0):

you can use `str.split` method
it works like `'a, b, c'.split(',') # or any other delimiter`

```
for line in csv_data:
    splitted = line.split('\t')
    print(splitted[0])
```

this is the most simple way
but the other more correct way is using [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module

```
pamreader = csv.reader(csv_data, delimiter='your delimeter')
for row in parmreader:
    print(row)
```